# Multiple infinte loops using async and await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to generate different objects and insert each object into it's respective `List` using await and async using the code below:

```
static List<ClassA> classAList = new List<ClassA>();
static List<ClassB> classBList = new List<ClassB>();

public async void GenerateUsers()
{
    await GenerateClassA();
    await GenerateClassB();
}

private static Task GenerateClassA()
{
   while(true)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(3000);
      classAList .Add(new ClassA());
      Console.WriteLine(classAList.Count);
   }
}

private static Task GenerateClassB()
{
   while (true)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(6000);
      classBList .Add(new ClassB());
      Console.WriteLine(classBList.Count)
   }
}
```

When I call `GenerateUsers` like

```
UserContainer uc = new UserContainer(); //Class GenerateUsers is defined
uc.GenerateUsers();

Console.WriteLine("Generating.....");
```

The program does not exit `GenerateClassA` and `Generating.....` is not printed to the screen.

How can I generate different objects in an infinite loop using `await` and `async` for each infinite loop.

Comment: Does it work without the second method call (await GenerateClassB())?

Comment: You don't have anything that is awaiting in the `GenerateClassA` or `GenerateClassB` so they are both running synchronously.  Additionally, if you want them to be running simultaneously, use `await Task.WhenAll(await GenerateClassA(), await GenerateClassB())`

Comment: The posted code will not compile. Either `GenerateClassA` explicitly returns a task (in which case it won't return to the calling thread until the `return` statement), or `GenerateClassA` is marked `async` (in which case the compiler warning will tell you exactly what's wrong). Either way, it runs synchronously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `await GenerateClassA();`, but `GenerateClassA` **doesn't do anything continuation related** - it simply run *to completion* promising to return a `Task`. Except: it can't run to completion, because `while(true)`. So yes, this won't work.

Something doesn't *become* async just beacause you add `async`. That *enables* genuinely async operations to be coordinated: nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Please could you explain what you mean by `doesn't do anything continuation related ` ?

Comment: @hello sure; when you `await GenerateClassA();`, that does one of two things: if the method returns a **completed** task, then it just carries on like normal code; otherwise, the code under the `await` is added as a *continuation callback* for when the task reports completion; in your case, however, not task is **ever** returned (complete or otherwise), so ... the `await` **is not even reached**; your code goes into `GenerateClassA` and *never comes out*. The `await` stuff depends on code following rules that your code just compeletely ignores.

Answer (score 3):

The methods you are calling are not `async`, and so they execute synchronously. Indeed, only the first method, `GenerateClassA()`, is ever even called. That method never returns, so you never get as far as calling the second. Probably you wanted something more like this:

```
public void GenerateUsers()
{
    GenerateClassA();
    GenerateClassB();
}

private static async void GenerateClassA()
{
   while(true)
   {
      await Task.Delay(3000);
      classAList.Add(new ClassA());
      Console.WriteLine(classAList.Count);
   }
}

private static async void GenerateClassB()
{
   while (true)
   {
      await Task.Delay(6000);
      classBList.Add(new ClassB());
      Console.WriteLine(classBList.Count)
   }
}
```

Note that the `void` return types prevent you from observing the tasks, such as exceptions that might occur. It's not advised. But it's consistent with the code you originally posted.